# Simultanious use of relative positioning and "of" notation

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

A rather high node has a not so high node on its rigth side.

I like the positioning and sizes, but i want both node to share the same Y-Axis of their north border.

```
\tikzstyle{big}  =[rectangle, draw=blue, text centered, minimum height=60]
\tikzstyle{small}=[rectangle, draw=black, text centered, minimum width=60]

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[big]   (l) {Left  High};
\node[small] (r) [right of = l, anchor = west] {Rigth  Low};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is a brute force example where only the Y-Axis alignes the way i would like it.

```
\node[big]   (l) at (0,0) [anchor = north] {Left High};
\node[small] (r) at (3,0) [anchor = north] {Right Low};
```

My goal is to still use the `[right of = l]` notation and also use reference `l.north` somehow to set `r.north = l.north`.

Comment: `right of` will position the node at a certain node distance from the other, by default using both the coordinate of their center; if you add `anchor`, you tell Tikz to refer to this coordinate to position the shape. Did you try `\node[right of=l.north,anchor=north]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably because you are using the positioning syntax with explicit `at (coord)` so that explicit coordinate wins over the positioning directive. Here are two examples

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
big/.style={rectangle, draw=blue, text centered, minimum height=60},
small/.style={rectangle, draw=black, text centered, minimum width=60}
]

\node[big] (l) at (0,0) {Left High};
\node[small,right= 3 cm of {l.north},anchor=north] (r) {Right Low};
\node[big,anchor=north west] (r2) at (r.north east) {righter};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]